# How do I convert an elevation shapefile into a CSV file with its XYZ data?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, data, dem, export

I am new to using QGIS and LeapfrogGeothermal Modeling.  I have a shapefile for Elevation and Altitude data and need to extract XYZ coordinates out of it? Can I do that? and how? and what kind of file do I need to change it to, to be able to use it?  I'm attempting to use this shapefile to create a solid topography surface but need the coordinates to upload into the program.

Comment: What do u call a shapefile "for Elevation and Altitude data" ? Did u check its content ? What are the geometries in it ? Points ? Polygons ?

Answer (score 2):

To extract your data open the attribute table and create a new field via fieldcalculator. Make sure to set datatype, precision and so on as you need it. Use `$y` to extract y-coordinate, `$x` to extract x-coordinate and `z($geometry)` to extract z-coordinate. (Not sure if `$z` will work).

[image]

In case you only want to extract coordinates and save them to a csv file, you can shorten up things by right-clicking your layer and choose `export as...`. Choose CSV and set geometry to `AS_XYZ`.

[image]